# How to construct a matrix with given vectors and scalars as eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I don't have an example but just wondering what if we are given a list of scalars and vectors, then how to write a matrix corresponding to those vectors and scalars as eigenvectors and eigenvalues using Jordan Canonical Form? Can someone give me some ideas on how to do this ? I want to know the specific steps applying Jordan Canonical Form.

Comment: Why do you want to use Jordan Canonical Form?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think maybe Jordan Form can solve this, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: The reason I am asking is that you can do this by just doing the reverse process of diagonalization

Comment: That's the point, I'm considering if the matrix is not diagonalizable then we cannot use the reverse process. That's to say the most general way to construct the matrix is using J.C.F, even when the matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean. I wrote an answer

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want to extend you vectors to a basis, write J.C.F. for the standard basis, then convert between the basis, and use this conversion to convert from J.C.F. to the matrix you want.

Suppose $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ are linearly independent column vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k$ are scalars. Extend $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ to a basis $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ for $\Bbb{R}^n$. Say $\{e_i\}$ is the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$. Form a matrix $A$ for a linear transformation which sends each $v_j$ to a standard basis vector $e_{i_j}$ (To make it easier, say that $i_{j_1} < i_{j_2}$ whenever $1 \leq j_1 <j_2 \leq k$). Let $P = 
\begin{bmatrix} J_{\lambda_1,i_1}&&&\\
& J_{\lambda_2,i_2-i_1}&&\\
&&\ddots&\\
&&&J_{\lambda_k,i_k-i_{k-1}}      
\end{bmatrix}$. Then, your matrix is $A^{-1}PA$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I mean is that now we have some vectors and some scalars corresponding to each vector, then how to construct a matrix whose eigenvectors and eigenvalues are the given ones.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I did that because if you have a $v_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$, then $A^{-1}PAv_j = A^{-1)Pe_{i_j}=A^{-1}(\lambda_j e_{i_j})=\lambda_j v_j$.